# How do I get all members the discord client can see?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to use the common method of:

```
for m in message.guild.members:
    print(m)
```

But it only gave out the bot himself no one different.
Any solution ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view members, you will need to activate members intents. You can find this in your Developer's portal located as in the image below.

[image: Members Intents in Red Box]

To activate intents, you will need to include the following in your code:

```py
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

 # Somewhere else (depending on what you're using):
 # client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
 # or
 # from discord.ext import commands
 # bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Other than that, your code should be working.

You can read more about [privileged intents here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents).